# Health check problem with setting up GKE with istio-gateway

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

#### Goal

I'm trying to setup a

```
Cloud LB -> GKE [istio-gateway -> my-service]
```

This was working before, however, I have to recreate the cluster 2 days ago and run into this problem. Maybe some version change?

This is my ingress manifest file

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "my-dev-ingress"
  namespace: "istio-system"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "my-dev-gclb-ip"
    ingress.gcp.kubernetes.io/pre-shared-cert: "my-dev-cluster-cert-05"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
spec:
  backend:
    serviceName: "istio-ingressgateway"
    servicePort: 80
```

#### Problem

The health check issue by the Cloud LB failed. The backend service created by the Ingress create a /:80 default health check.

#### What I have tried

1)  I tried to set the health check generated by the gke ingress to point to the istio-gateway StatusPort port 15020 in the Backend config console. Then the health check passed for a bit until the backend config revert itself to use the original /:80 healthcheck that it created. I even tried to delete the healthcheck that it created and it just create another one.

2)  I also tried using the istio-virtual service to route the healthcheck to 15020 port as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/integrating-https-load-balancing-with-istio-and-cloud-run-for-anthos-deployed-on-gke#handling_health_check_requests) with out much success.

3) I also tried just route everything in the virtual-service the healthcheck port

```
  hosts:
    - "*"
  gateways:
    - my-web-gateway
  http:
    - match:
        - method:
            exact: GET
          uri:
            exact: /
      route:
        - destination:
            host: istio-ingress.gke-system.svc.cluster.local
            port:
              number: 15020
```

4) Most of the search result I found say that setting `readinessProbe` in the deployment should tell the ingress to set the proper health check. However, all of my service are under the istio-gateway and I can't really do the same.

I'm very lost right now and will really appreciate it if anyone could point me to the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Hi, what are the istio and gke versions? Is it open source istio or gke addon? Did You redo entire gke cluter or were the existing elements used? If its possible the previous version of istio would help as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The GKE is 1.14.10-gke.36. I'm sorry I could not find information on the istio version I will keep looking. I tried both fixing up the current cluster and created a brand new cluster with istio enabled option (which I assume it's the gke addon) and both have the same result. I will see if I can revert the gke cluster to the previous version of istio thanks

Comment: Have You managed to solve this issue? GKE should add health check based on Your yaml files. Check if maybe on LB there are more than one Health checks / backends that could be causing issues.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info, we have not solved the issues, and we were making it health check directly the web app right inside the istio, which is not idea, but it's our only workaround now. As you advised I did check if there is more than one health checks, but could not find any other.

Answer (score 2):

i got it working with gke 1.20.4-gke.2200 and istio 1.9.2, the documentation for this is non existent or i have not found anything, you have to add an annotation to istio-ingressgateway service to use a backend-config when using "istioctl install -f values.yaml" command

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
      - name: istio-ingressgateway
        enabled: true
        k8s:
          serviceAnnotations:
            cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"default": "istio-ingressgateway-config"}'
```

then you have to create the backend-config with the correct healthcheck port

```
apiVersion: cloud.google.com/v1
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: istio-ingressgateway-config
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  healthCheck:
    checkIntervalSec: 30
    port: 15021
    type: HTTP
    requestPath: /healthz/ready
```

with this the ingress should automatically change the configuration for the load balancer health check pointing to istio port 80

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: istio-system
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: web
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: "web"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: test.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: "/*"
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: istio-ingressgateway
                port:
                  number: 80
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: direct-web
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  hosts:
    - test.example.com
  gateways:
    - web
  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            prefix: "/"
      route:
        - destination:
            port:
              number: 8080 #internal service port
            host: "internal-service.service-namespace.svc.cluster.local"
```

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: web
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - test.example.com
```

you could also set hosts to "*" in the virtualservice and gateway

Comment: The BackendConfig was the key to my success. I was previously following this guide: https://www.padok.fr/en/blog/https-istio-kubernetes which was working too, but it involved using a virtual service to kind of hack around this. The BackendConfig is a much cleaner way to do it, at least in 2023. You can also find docs on BackendConfig's here now: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-configuration#direct_health

Comment: Here is a gist of my culmination of the above: https://gist.github.com/nickzelei/b9ce328eba705723ff9ed7a52f64ea0b